# LG G6: Remove the "Clear All" button from the recent apps menu

Tags: recents-screen, lg-g6, usability

My LG G6 has a "Clear All" button in its recent apps menu which annoys me big time because I often hit it accidentally. Is there a way to remove it?

I found [a petition](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgg6/comments/6ckcn2/petition_to_move_the_clear_all_apps_button_from/) on Reddit, and [a manual workaround](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgg6/comments/6fcz2z/remove_the_clear_all_option_in_recent_apps/diigeds/) (pinning the apps you need most), but no complete solution.

[image]